# Non greedy regex pattern for email Python

Tags: python, regex

I m new to regular expression and stuck at this situation where my current regex pattern is returning two results and one of them starting with the phone no. (String doesn't have a space between phone no and email). I tried using the ? to make expression non greedy but its not returning anything.

###### Code

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%.?-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b')

matches = pattern.finditer(Clean)

for match in matches:
   print(match.group(0))
```

###### Output

```
9012345678testemail.grp@gmail.com
support@testtest.com
```

###### Expected Output

```
testemail.grp@gmail.com
```

Comment: what are you trying to extract with regex ? Only the email address bit (without phone number) ?

Comment: Greedy-ness is not related, it simply returns *all* matches

Comment: not sure if email addresses can start with a digit (guessing: no). if so, forbid the first character to be a digit

Comment: How do i do that? I don't need expression to look for another email and stop at first match.

Comment: Please add an *Expected output* in your Q, as it is still not clear what you are trying to accomplish... get only the first result and then stop??

Comment: Apologies, edited with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]+[\w.-]*@[a-z]+[.][a-z]+")
```

`[a-zA-Z]` -> the email starts with a letter

`\w` -> any letter, digit or an underscores

`[\w.-]*` -> 0 or more letters, digits, underscores, ., or -

`[a-z]+` -> a lower case domain 1 or more characters long

`[.]` -> put the `.` in square brackets, cuz . has a special meaning in regex

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]+[\w.-]*@[a-z]+[.][a-z]+")
matches = pattern.findall("aar@g.com ooo11..com hellow_world@hello.world 1234hey@hey.com")
print(matches)
```

Result:

```
['aar@g.com', 'hellow_world@hello.world', 'hey@hey.com']
```